# Find the extremals of the functional $\int\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}dx$?

Tags: polar-coordinates, calculus-of-variations

I want to use the polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. After transformation, I get $$\int r\sqrt{r^2+(r')^2}d\theta.$$
Then, I derived the Euler-Lagrange equation $$2r^2-rr''+3(r')^2=0.$$
I get the solutions to this ODE, but it doesn't match the solutions.
$$\theta+C_1=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{r^4-C^2}}{C}), \text{ where } C,C_1\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Solution is  $x^2\cos(\alpha)+2xy\sin(\alpha)-y^2\cos(\alpha)=\beta$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are constants.

Comment: Well, as the next step you should go back to the rectangular coordinates to see if you can get the proposed solution. I admit to have had some problems with this in the past and I wasn't able to resolve it. As a small contribution, I've tried the alternative way of using [Beltrami's identity][1] as the integrand does not depend on $\theta$. I got a first order differential equation ($r'=r\sqrt{r^3-c^2}/c^2$) with a solution similar to yours. Maybe someone can be more helpful.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity

Comment: Shouldn't $\int r\sqrt{r^2+(r')^2}d\theta$ be $\int r(t) \sqrt{r'(t)^2+r(t)^2 \theta'(t)^2} dt$?

Comment: @md2perpe. Not really. If you consider that $dx=\cos\theta dr-\sin\theta d\theta$ and $dy=dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta$, the $dx^2+dy^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$. In the end $dx\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}=d\theta\sqrt{r^2+(dr/d\theta)^2}$. Obviously $y$ is a function of $x$, $r$ is a function of $\theta$, $dy/dx=y'(x)$ and $dr/d\theta=r'(\theta)$

Comment: @Marco81. Yes, I saw later that one gets that integral when parameterizing w.r.t. $\theta$.